# How to wait only for certain time to get response of HTTP request (GET/POST) in angular 2?

Tags: http, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, observable

How to wait only for certain time to get the response of HTTP request (GET/POST) in angular 2 otherwise break the HTTP request?

I had a look on `timeout` and `setTimeInterval` functions but those do not break the HTTP request within specified time limit.

Basically, what I am trying to do is break the HTTP request (whether get or post) if it doesn't get the response within 5 seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use rxjs timeout() and pass time in miliseconds.

```
this.http.get('url').timeout(5000).map(data => data.json());
```

Comment: It throws exception "timeout is not a function". Do I need to import something?

Comment: Try - import 'rxjs/operator/timeout'

Comment: i think this does not work anymore with HttpClient: error TS2339: Property 'timeout' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'

Answer (score 2):

For a the newer versions of RXJS use the .pipe() method with the timeout like:

```
import { timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get('url').pipe(timeout(5000)).map(data => data.json());
```